# Correct way to use an array of SKUs to filter collection results in M2

Tags: magento-2.1, filter, product-collection, object-manager

Working with Magento EE v2.1.7.

I have an arbitrary array of SKUs that I wish to use to filter the products I'm returning on all category pages. I've created a custom module to generate this array dynamically based on business requirements. It can have one result or many results. Here is an example:

```
array("sku"=>"100010","sku"=>"100037","sku"=>"820654")
```

but I can also prep it for use with a collection:

```
array(
    array('attribute'=>'sku','eq'=>100010),
    array('attribute'=>'sku','eq'=>100037),
    array('attribute'=>'sku','eq'=>820654)
)
```

With this module I can pass the array anywhere its needed within Magento. While I can find many references to "adding attributes to filter" for Magento's collections, I'm not certain how to apply to ALL catalog results. From my understanding, it's possible to pass this information to the collection filter so that it tries each SKU with the OR operator in the query. The final result if I were using the sample array of 3 products above would be 3 product listings on the category page.

So do I need to interface with M2's object manager or is there a simpler yet acceptable way to present the filter data to the product collection? How would I begin to filter a catalog collection with these SKUs?

Comment: As catalog results also come from list.phtml you can filter the collection recieved in list.phtml itself after overriding it in your module of course.